# .net mvc problem with packages id partial view

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

[Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Nrp1.png)

Hi,
I'm having a problem with Partial View in .NET MVC App. When I try to add it, I get an error (the one one screenshoot).
Can someone help me solve this problem?
Best Regards.

Comment: Please list the steps that you have tried to fix the error. Including restarting Visual Studio, rebuilding the projects, clearing cache etc.

Comment: Restore the nuget packages and have look into your package.config file because sometime we have sudden open and add some unrelated data.

Comment: The problem is in the file listed in the screen shot; *packages.config*. If you add that (i.e. what is in that file) to your question, it may be someone can point you to the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Try the followings one by one:

- Disable the automatically package checking option from visual studio *Tools > Options... menu* before you add a partial view to the project. After that enable the package checking option.
  [image]
- Open the *.csproj file with notepad and manually add the new file in there (following the existing file name with path). e.g.:
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your packages.config file.

This is an example row on packages.config file:

```
<package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.0" targetFramework="net452" />
```

If your word `id` is capitalize, try to change it to lower case, do it for all the record.